# React Router Dom v6 Redirect issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have writter "replace" but it is still not working.

```
<Route 
     path="/"
     element={<Navigate to="https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=**********&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login" replace />}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're navigating to an external route.
You can make a similar component, e.g. `NavigateExernal` as illustrated below. Within that component, just update `window.location.href` inside `useEffect()` or `componentDidMount` if you're component is a class.

```
// use NavigateExternal instead of Navigate
<Route path="enter" element={<NavigateExternal to="https://www.google.com" />} />


// NavigateExternal.tsx
import { useEffect } from "react"

const NavigateExternal = ({ to }: { to: string }) => {
  useEffect(() => { window.location.href = to })
  return null
}

export default NavigateExternal
```

Comment: @ProdiptaBanerjee React Router's documentation around use of anchor tags and external routing could be better. Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.